# How to Document/ Map GUI transitions & states for embedded applications

Tags: user-interface, documentation, qml, uml

I have been working on a GUI application. In QtQuick, QML, C++.

**This is an Embedded Application, Not a Website**

**Short Question**

How to document my GUI flow and make map of all the screens and components used in it.

Now im using word to

`make a rough sctech using box and lines -->
Make it a picture --> Paste in excel --> use hyperlinks to track transitions.`

But it is not professional and time consuming.

**Detailed question**

The main purpose of documentng is, so that other programmers can understnad the desing easily and develop C++ code easily.

I want to document my GUI, like it should answer the following questions

```
1.How many screens do I have,
2.What is the relation between them
3.How the flow is happening
4.What are the components should I create and such basic questions.
```

Since i'm using QML, the GUI logic is separate from C++ Code

I have seen people mentioning `State transition charts` , `wireframing` and `UML`.

Is it suitable for embedded applications, Is it the right track to go?

I want to do the documentation process quickly and without stress.

An example would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create a State Machine Diagram. This is UML terminology for a state transition chart. Every screen is a state; while the application shows screen X, the application is in state X. The transitions specify how the user may navigate from one screen to another. You may label the transitions by the actions the user takes to navigate, but if you just want to give an overview of the screens and their relationships, you may omit these labels. See figures 13 and 14 in my paper [Which UML models should we make?](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf) or have a look at [UI flow diagrams on www.agilemodeling.com](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/uiFlowDiagram.htm).

To model the components inside a screen, I would recommend a separate wireframe sketch for each screen. For more information, see [usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/wireframing.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use [Wire Framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe). UML tools (e.g. [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/webinar/design/wireframe/introduction/modeling-wireframes-for-mobile-apps-and-webpages.html)) provide appropriate profiles where you can show screens on diagrams and link them with e.g. a MVC model. Note that although Wire Framing is mostly used in Web Design it can well be used in embedded systems (e.g. a cell phone is an embedded system with just web access).

Comment: Is wireframing really useful for making my team understand my GUI. How do you justify? with some examples if possible... Becuase the wireframe I make and my final product wont be the same.. I cannot dynamically keep updating my wireframe also.

Comment: Follow the EA link above. They have a couple of examples (and a video).